# Is the function is differentiable at $x$ or $D$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I know that a) and b) is differentiable  at the given points, would you maybe explain how I should show that ?

a) $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad x\rightarrow 0,{ \quad x }_{ 0 }=0$

b) $f:\mathbb{R}^{ - }\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad x\rightarrow 1/|x|,\quad D=\mathbb{R}^{ - }$

Thank you !

Comment: Any effort? Do you know $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions? Since you are new here, read [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: No sorry, i just know that if the left and right-limit of the function have the same value , we can say that the function is differentiable at that point

Comment: But thx anyway for warning!:)

Answer (score 2):

For *a*, as you defined $f$ to be a constant function $0$, so it is continuous differentiable function on $\mathbb R$. Just, apply the definition: $$f'(x_0)=f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}x=0$$ For $b$, I assume $\mathbb R^-$ means we had excluded $0$ from our domain. So the function $f$ became: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}\longrightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{-x}, x\in\mathbb R^-$$ Now take $x_0\in D$ be an arbitrary number, so $f$ is defined at it because $x_0\neq 0$ and so: $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{1/x-1/x_0}{x-x_0}$$ I think the latter limit is so easy to be solved.

Comment: Nicely explained. I find your answers really helpful and encouraging! +1